# Forms authentication - changing loginUrl at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I have something like this in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="MyVirtualDirectory/Login/Login" protection="All" timeout="15" />
</authentication>
```

However, I'm trying to implement some "fake" virtual directories and can't seem to figure out how to make the "MyVirtualDirectory" part of the loginUrl dynamic at runtime.

[Reading this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.loginurl.aspx), it appears that I can just set this property, however adding it to Application_Start or Application_BeginRequest doesn't seem to work.

Any help? Thanks!